# robotium, how to test listview

Tags: android, unit-testing, robotium

how can I test listview by robotium? I just want to check if oncreate event the items goes into it.

my Activity has a method:

```
private void initListView() {
    Adapter adapter = 
            new Adapter(this, myRepository.findAll());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

MyRepository returns List. In the ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 I want to put some items into respository and then test if listView contains elements.

```
public void testListView_IsNotEmpty() {
    Item i = new Item();
    i.setSomething("item1");
    getActivity().getMyRepository().insert(i);
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("item1"));
}
```

Is it via robotium possible do to that?

best regards

Comment: Can you access the repository __before__ your call `getActivity()` in the test case? Just add the text before, your activity will not be created until you actually call through to `getActivity()`. Otherwise, register a `DataSetObserver` in your adapter and call that when you mess with your repository.

Comment: thx for help but I can't load data before activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clear case for mocking  framework. I recomment jMockit as it is most advanced  and suitable to use against stubbed out android libraries.   As you do not like to test classes provided by android itself ( you implicitely trust that they do right thing )  , you only have to test that:

- your repositry was asked for value list
- this value list was used to create an adapter
- this adapter was passed to list view

Test case would look like this:

```
@Test
public void testThatListInitializedProperly(@Mocked final ListView listView,
                                            @Mocked final YourRepository repository,
                                            @Mocked(methods = {"initListView"}, inverse=true) final YourActivity activity, 
                                            @Mocked final Adapter adapter
 ) {
    new Expectations() {
        {
               repository.findAll(); returns(someList);

               new Adapter(activity, someList); returns(adapter);

               listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    };

    activity.initListView(listView);
```

}

(note that I adjusted interface for easier mockability )